# Assigning widget Views in Fragments

Tags: android-fragments

I just recently started working with Fragments and am reading different opinions on which method you should assign all of your widget Views in. It seems logical to do in in the on create view method but my text book shows all of the assignments made in the onStart method instead. Is there a correct answer to this and what are the advantages of making all of the assignments in onStart instead? Thank you.

Comment: Anything after the onCreateView() (after inflation) is fine. onStart() comes after onCreateView() so, ... 
Have a look at the lifecycle of Fragments. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3QW.png

Comment: ok, thanks. Is it fine to  just keep them in the onCreateView() method then?